# Multiplying a 2D (5x3) array by a 1D (5x1) array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to ask a question about multiplying 2D arrays by a 1D array.

I have the following 2 numpy arrays:

```
>> array1_test
array([14.0067, 12.0107, 12.0107, 15.9994, 12.0107])

>> array2_test
array([[49.725, 20.724, 59.915],
       [51.168, 20.935, 60.26 ],
       [51.32 , 21.167, 61.757],
       [50.327, 21.247, 62.472],
       [51.732, 22.136, 59.483]])
```

I want to multiply each row in `array2_test` by the corresponding float in the position of `array1_test`.

I tried this using a while loop:

```
i = 0
while i < len(array2_test):
    print(array1_test[i] * array2_test[i])
    i += 1
```

which yields my expected result:

```
[696.4831575 290.2748508 839.2114305]
[614.5634976 251.4440045 723.764782 ]
[616.389124  254.2304869 741.7447999]
[805.2018038 339.9392518 999.5145168]
[621.3375324 265.8688552 714.4324681]
```

but I would like to store these in an array of the form:

```
array([[696.4831575 290.2748508 839.2114305],
[614.5634976 251.4440045 723.764782 ],
[616.389124  254.2304869 741.7447999],
[805.2018038 339.9392518 999.5145168],
[621.3375324 265.8688552 714.4324681]])
```

I tried to do the following:

```
i = 0
mylist = []
while i < len(array2_test):
    mylist += (array1_test[i] * array2_test[i])
    i += 1
```

but that yields no result.

How can such a result be achieved?

My intuition was to convert the multiplication result into a list and append to `mylist` but as I am required to return an array, I was wondering whether a shorter solution was possible.

Comment: Is that `numpy` array?

Comment: @Guy yes. `from numpy import array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to turn the 1-D array of shape `(5,)` into a 2-D array of shape `(5, 1)` by slicing with `None` (which creates a new axis). This allows you to simply multiply the arrays together and let NumPy handle the rest:

```py
>>> array2_test * array1_test[:, None]
array([[696.4831575, 290.2748508, 839.2114305],
       [614.5634976, 251.4440045, 723.764782 ],
       [616.389124 , 254.2304869, 741.7447999],
       [805.2018038, 339.9392518, 999.5145168],
       [621.3375324, 265.8688552, 714.4324681]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`reshape` is enough here:

```
array2_test * array1_test.reshape((5,1)
```

gives as expected:

```
array([[696.4831575, 290.2748508, 839.2114305],
       [614.5634976, 251.4440045, 723.764782 ],
       [616.389124 , 254.2304869, 741.7447999],
       [805.2018038, 339.9392518, 999.5145168],
       [621.3375324, 265.8688552, 714.4324681]])
```